# Update column based on lead function in oracle

Tags: oracle19c

I have valid_from and valid_to columns in a table.
I need to update the valid_to column based on the next row of valid_from column.

Please help me on this.

Current

| Runid | Valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-Jan-21 | 10-Jan-21 |
| 1 | 11-Jan-21 | 11-Jan-21 |
| 1 | 15-Jan-21 | 17-Jan-21 |
| 1 | 18-Jan-21 | 1-Jan-00 |

Desired

| Runid | Valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-Jan-21 | 11-Jan-21 |
| 1 | 11-Jan-21 | 15-Jan-21 |
| 1 | 15-Jan-21 | 18-Jan-21 |
| 1 | 18-Jan-21 | 1-Jan-00 |

Comment: Please include all relevant as _text_, directly in your question.  External links may break over time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEAD` function and correlate on the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
UPDATE table_name t
SET valid_to = (SELECT next_from
                FROM   (
                  SELECT LEAD(valid_from, 1, valid_to)
                           OVER (PARTITION BY runid ORDER BY valid_from) AS next_from
                  FROM   table_name
                ) x
                WHERE x.ROWID = t.ROWID
               )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Runid, Valid_from, valid_to) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-01-11', DATE '2021-01-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-01-15', DATE '2021-01-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2021-01-18', DATE '4000-01-11' FROM DUAL;
```

Updates the table to:

> | RUNID | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00 |
> | 1 | 2021-01-11 00:00:00 | 2021-01-15 00:00:00 |
> | 1 | 2021-01-15 00:00:00 | 2021-01-18 00:00:00 |
> | 1 | 2021-01-18 00:00:00 | 4000-01-01 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=950a816674e77beb01a89d6373d544af)*